# What kind of input data are the following sorting algorithms good/bad for?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What kind of data input are the following sorting algorithms efficient on/not efficient on? Quicksort, Mergesort, Heapsort, Insertion sort etc.

I know there are at least 2 factors that affect the performance of a sorting algorithm: 1) The size of the input, and 2) whether or not the data is already mostly sorted. But I don't know exactly how these factors affect the efficiency of the algorithms.

I'd like to study this in detail, so if there are any sources/links that you can point me to, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming quicksort is based on Hoare partition scheme (middle value as pivot), then it won't degrade to worst case time complexity of O(n^2) for almost sorted data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

Mergesort always does n ⌈log2(n)⌉ moves. If data is already sorted, then the number of compares is about (⌈n ⌈log2(n)⌉)/2.

Heapsort time complexity remains about the same (duplicates may reduce running time).

Insertion sort is the only sort in this list that is faster if the data is nearly sorted, but it's time complexity is O(n^2). I'm thinking that for nearly sorted data, the time complexity would be ~ O(m n), where m is the number of elements out of place.

Variations of natural merge sort, which might use insertion sort on small runs while scanning and identifying already sorted runs, would have time complexity O(n) on already sorted data.

Comment: appart from sorting it also depends on the memory that must be taken into consideration for eg, merge sort take the much memory compared to other

Comment: @prashantrana - true, but this wouldn't be an issue unless the size of the input was more than 1/2 available memory, in which case [block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) could be used, but it's slower than standard merge sort. Block merge sort is affected by the data, as it runs best if there are at least 2 · sqrt(n) unique values in the array to be sorted, as those are used to create working areas while allowing block merge sort to remain stable.